# по клику перейти на другую страницу и открыть модальное окно на новой странице

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

возможно ли это? если да то подскажите

Answer (score 2):

Можно испльзовать hash. На новой странице делайте проверку есть ли такой-то хеш и открывайте модалку

```
<a href="/path#something">Go</a>

// На новой странице делаем проверку
if(window.location.hash === '#something') {
   // Open modal
}
```

Или как-то через localStorage делать манипуляции з данными. Добавлять и удалять поля