# Можно ли сделать ссылку на "действие"?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть в наличии:

```
<a href="#" id="menu-link">
  <span class="menu-sub">Открыть</span>
  <span class="menu-main">Меню</span>
</a>
<div id="menu-wrap">
  <div id="menu-inner">
    <h1 id="menu-title">Оглавление</h1>
    <a href="#" id="close">x</a>
```

Это index.html при нажатии на надпись "Открыть меню" у нас затемняется фоновое изображение и открывается меню, каким образом я могу сделать ссылку с другого ресурса сразу на открытое меню? Дабы не заставлять пользователя снова нажимать кнопку "открыть меню"

script.js

```
    var $menuWrap = $('#menu-wrap'),
    $body = $('body'),
    $menuTitle = $('#menu-title'),
    $close = $('#close'),
    $menuCards = $('.menu-card'),
    $menuInner = $('#menu-inner'),
    $menuLink = $('#menu-link');

  setCardHeight();
  $(window).resize(setCardHeight);

  $menuLink.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    showOverlay();
  });

  $close.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    hideOverlay();
  });

  function showOverlay() {
    $body.addClass('menu-on');
    $menuWrap.addClass('display').addClass('visible');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $menuTitle.addClass('on');
      $close.addClass('on');
    }, 200);
    $menuCards.each(function(i) {
      var $card = $(this);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $card.addClass('on');
      }, 200 + 50 * i);
    });
  }

  function hideOverlay() {
    $body.removeClass('menu-on');
    $menuCards.removeClass('on');
    $menuTitle.removeClass('on');
    $close.removeClass('on');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $menuWrap.removeClass('display').removeClass('visible');
    }, 350);
  }

  function setCardHeight() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var topVal;
    if (windowWidth >= 1300) {
      topVal = ($(window).height() - 700) / 2;
    } else {
      topVal = ($(window).height() - 200 - (windowWidth / 1300 * 513)) / 2;
    }
    if (topVal < 10) {
      topVal = 10;
    }
    $menuInner.css('top', topVal);
  }
```

Comment: В адрес можно добавить параметр GET запроса, а из скрипта проверять его на наличие. Соответственно таким образом по умолчанию меню не открывается, а если со значением ?show_menu=true, то открывается при запуске.

Comment: в самом скрипте мне нужно что то дописывать?

Comment: само собой. Данный параметр лишь флаг. Сам он ничего делать не будет. :)

Comment: Подскажите что и как или это долго и муторно? Или может направите на статью?

Comment: посмотрите на window.location.

Comment: Совсем забыл что есть ещё файл script.js с содержанием:

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать ссылку с хешем. Вот похожий вопрос, только человеку нужно было модальное окно открывать а не меню:

[по клику перейти на другую страницу и открыть модальное окно на новой странице](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1170483/%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83-%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5/1170489#1170489)